# Make an jButton ImageIcon move between 2 jButtons in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make the image icon of `ballpos` move between two `JButton`s in my `JButton` array. These are buttons 99 and 108 on every press of a separate `JButton jBAct`, so that on every press of `jBAct` the image will move one down to 99 then once reached 99 will go up to 108 then go back down to 99 again and so on.

Here is what I've tried, i know it's wrong but i think it's along these lines.

```
if (event.getSource() == jBAct)
{
    if (ballpos > 99)
    {
        jBGame[ballpos-1].setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/ball.png"));
        jBGame[ballpos].setIcon(new ImageIcon());
        ballpos--;
    } else {
        if (ballpos < 108){
            jBGame[ballpos+1].setIcon(new ImageIcon("src/ball.png"));
            jBGame[ballpos].setIcon(new ImageIcon());
            ballpos++;
        }
    }
}
```

This code segment is in class `public class CBabyBallBounce extends JFrame implements ActionListener`
and part of method `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)`

Comment: "*i know it's wrong*" How? Describe why the behavior of your code is not what you want.

Comment: The icon is in a starting position of 100. When jBAct is pressed it moves down to 99, when pressed it goes up to 100. When pressed again it goes down to 99 and so forth.

Comment: Right, so the thing to realize here is that if I tell you that currently that the icon is at 102, you can't know where to move it to in the next press (103 or 101). This tells you that something has to remember the direction in which it should move, right?

Comment: Ok I understand what you're saying, so how would I go about getting it to remember which direction it should move in?

Comment: The code you posted is inside some class, probably an `ActionListener`? You can have a field there that holds the direction value. I would post the class surrounding your given code in order to give us context. Also fix the missing `}`.

Comment: I don't want the whole class, just the context for your code to serve as an example.

Comment: OK, [edit] your question with this and I'll post an answer.

Comment: I have edited my question, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direction in which the ball moves is not kept anywhere in your code, so when a ball reaches a position between 99 and 108 you can't know in which direction to move it. I suggest keeping this information in the `ActionListener` responsible for this behavior.

In the following example I have an array of 4 buttons between which the ball moves. I represent the ball with a `String`, but the concept is the same for an image.

```
public class Buttons {

    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[4];
    JButton move = new JButton("Move");

    private final String text = "O";

    Buttons() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
            panel.add(buttons[i] = new JButton());
        buttons[2].setText(text);

        move.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            private int ballpos = 2;
            private int dir = 1;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buttons[ballpos].setText(null);
                ballpos += dir;
                buttons[ballpos].setText(text);
                if (ballpos == buttons.length - 1)
                    dir = -1;
                else if (ballpos == 0)
                    dir = 1;
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.add(move, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Buttons());
    }
}
```

I would highly recommend to add an `ActionListener` per button or group of buttons that share the same behavior as I did above. It allows you to *encapsulate* the behavior of the button. Do not have the frame implement a "global" `ActionListener` and then find the source of the event by `if-else` statements. This leads to a mess and more bugs.

The code inside `actionPerformed` can be slightly cleverer, but I went for readable for this example. If you understand it you can change it in a number of different ways.

As a final note, don't create a new image icon each time. Crate the image once and store it as I did for my string (which, for a string, is redundant, since `String`s are special). You can also use `null` instead of an empty image, again, as I did for the string case.